# Pentaho : Executing a Job multiple times with different Params - Params are not sent over to Job

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a Pentaho "Job" that should be executed multiple times, each time with a different param value. 
I indeed have a similar set up as we see in this link https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/Job_Executor

The Job does get executed as many times as the number of rows, although the different parameter values are not passed onto the Job. If I add a write to Log in the job it does not print the different values.

Comment: Have you created the parameters in the job file and then assigned fields to them in the Parameters tab of the job executor?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it was a defect in 8.1.x. Upgraded to 8.2.x and it is resolved.